# Calculate the mode of a list of integers?

Tags: f#, average

Is there a built-in function to calculate the mode of a list of integers in F#?

If I have a list of integers, as follows:

```
let integers = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 3]
```

I would expect the result to be `3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such built-in function. Here is a naive implementation for you:

```
let mode = function
    | [] -> None
    | xs -> 
        let mostFrequentTwo =
            xs
            |> Seq.groupBy id 
            |> Seq.map (fun (n, ns) -> n, Seq.length ns)
            |> Seq.sortByDescending snd
            |> Seq.truncate 2
            |> Seq.toList

        match mostFrequentTwo with
        | [(x, xSize); (_, ySize)] when xSize > ySize -> Some x
        | [(x, _)] -> Some x
        | _ -> None
```

First it groups the numbers in the list, then takes the size of each group, then sorts the groups by their size in descending order, then picks the first two. If there are two groups and the first one is larger, then that is the mode; if there is just one group, then it is the mode; otherwise there is no mode.

I call this implementation "naive", because it does some things that are strictly speaking unnecessary: a better approach would be to first sort the numbers, then go over them just enough to see the first two groups, and compare their sizes. However, that would be more complex to write and harder to understand, yet the computational complexity of the above solution is still `n * log n` (or even linear, depending on the grouping and sorting implementations), so it doesn't seem necessary to optimize before seeing performance data.

Comment: Note that there's `Seq.countBy`, which is equivalent to your `Seq.groupBy id >> Seq.map (...)`.